# How to avoid copy pasting hasRole or hasPermission annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have plenty of methods which I have to annotate with this annotation:

```
@Override
@PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject.id, 'mypackage.SecuredClazz', 'ADMINISTRATION')")
public MyObject findSectionAById(SomeId id) {
    ////the code
}
```

The annotation is even more complex, it includes `hasRole` and different `hasPermission` conditions. Many objects are implementing `mypackage.SecuredClazz` and have ids. As a result I have plenty of copy paste annotations with the same body:

```
@PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject.id, 'mypackage.SecuredClazz', 'ADMINISTRATION')")
```

Is it possible to use other annotation or other way not to copy this whole line to 100 methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own annotation which includes the described annotation:

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject.id, 'mypackage.SecuredClazz', 'ADMINISTRATION')"
public @interface SecuredClazzAuthorized { }
```

Usage:

```java
@Override
@SecuredClazzAuthorized
public MyObject findSectionAById(SomeId id) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a meta annotation, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#method-security-meta-annotations):

> **Method Security Meta Annotations**
>
> You can make use of meta annotations for method security to make your code more readable. This is especially convenient if you find that you are repeating the same complex expression throughout your code base. For example, consider the following:
>
> ```java
> @PreAuthorize("#contact.name == authentication.name")
> ```
>
> Instead of repeating this everywhere, we can create a meta annotation that can be used instead.
>
> ```java
> @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
> @PreAuthorize("#contact.name == authentication.name")
> public @interface ContactPermission {}
> ```
>
> Meta annotations can be used for any of the Spring Security method security annotations. In order to remain compliant with the specification JSR-250 annotations do not support meta annotations.